# Re-use a defined variable in multiple Nightwatchjs test steps

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

Ok, so I know this is probably going to be something obvious and straightforward, but I just can't seem to get it to work.

Using the Nigthwatchjs [perform](https://nightwatchjs.org/api/perform.html#apimethod-page) command, I'm trying to re-use a variable from a step into the next step.

Below is a snippet of my code from my test script;

```
'2) Breadcrumbs': function (browser) {
    browser.perform(function() {
        var testMake = browser.globals.specsTestMake;
        var testModel = browser.globals.specsTestModel;
        var testRange = browser.globals.specsTestRange;
        var testYear = browser.globals.specsTestYear;
        browser.assert.containsText('nav.site-breadcrumbs', 'Home', testMake, testModel, testRange, testYear, 'specs');
        console.log('test make from step 2 = ', testMake);
    });
},
'3) Heading': function (browser) {
    browser.perform(function(testMake, done) {
        console.log('test make from step 3 = ', testMake);
        done();
    });
},
```

The *console.log* from the first step, '*2) Breadcrumbs*' is correctly displayed (for this test example) as BMW, as defined in the globals file.

I therefore thought that the *console.log* for the second step, '*3) Heading*' would also be correctly displayed as BMW.

However, this is not the case.

The second *console.log* displays what appears to be the entire page, settings, etc.

A small snippet is below;

```
 ✔ 2) Breadcrumbs (26ms)

 test make from step 3 =  { capabilities:

 { acceptInsecureCerts: true,

 acceptSslCerts: true,

 applicationCacheEnabled: false,

 browserConnectionEnabled: false,

 browserName: 'chrome',

 chrome:

  { chromedriverVersion: '2.44.609545 (c2f88692e98ce7233d2df7c724465ecacfe74df5)',

    userDataDir:

     '/var/folders/6x/3kzp0zhd6vv0q_mfstkxd73m0000gr/T/.org.chromium.Chromium.iDQCXI' },

 cssSelectorsEnabled: true,

 databaseEnabled: false,

 'goog:chromeOptions': { debuggerAddress: 'localhost:52102' },

 handlesAlerts: true,
```

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong with my perform command?

Thanks